# How to use GROUP BY Clasuse in Sql query to show unique data with multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my 2 Mysql table :

**logger :**

```
lg_tbl_id     lg_id           ch_id    lg_name    created
============================================================
29            1583ecb93dd121  8        D4L08841   1480510355
30            1583ecb93dd121  9        D4L08841   1480510355
31            1583eccf794e0e  14       D4L08842   1480510711
```

**channel**

```
ch_id    ch_name    ch_for        created
============================================
8        CH01       Watter Level  1480247466
9        CH02       Watter Level  1480247474
10       CH31       Watter Level  1480247480
11       CH32       Watter Level  1480247485
12       CHO5       Watter Level  1480506405
13       CHO6       Watter Level  1480506409
14       CHO7       Watter Level  1480506413
```

Using bellow sql query it's showing following data :

```
 $getLogger = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT logger.lg_name, logger.lg_id, logger.created, channel.ch_name 
 FROM logger 
 LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.ch_id = logger.ch_id 
 ORDER BY logger.lg_tbl_id DESC");

while ( $fetchLogger = mysqli_fetch_array($getLogger) ) {

      $lg_id      = $fetchLogger['lg_id'];
      $lg_name    = htmlspecialchars($fetchLogger['lg_name']);
      $ch_name    = htmlspecialchars($fetchLogger['ch_name']);
      $created    = $fetchLogger['created'];
      $created    = date("Y-m-d h:m:s A", $created);

      // table data showing here....
}
```

**Data Return :**

```
id              Logger name     Channel Name   created 
1583eccf794e0e  D4L08842        CHO7           2016-11-30 01:11:31 PM
1583ecb93dd121  D4L08841        CH02           2016-11-30 01:11:35 PM
1583ecb93dd121  D4L08841        CH01           2016-11-30 01:11:35 PM
```

Now you see that **id** and **Logger name** column contain duplicate **id** and **Logger name**. For e.g **1583ecb93dd121** and **D4L08841** showing twice with **2** different **Channel Name**

I want to show Unique **id** and **Logger name** with all **Channel Name** in one row. Like bellow :

```
1583ecb93dd121  D4L08841        CH01, CH02       2016-11-30 01:11:35 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT logger.lg_name, logger.lg_id, logger.created,
GROUP_CONCAT(channel.ch_name) as ch_name
FROM logger 
LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.ch_id = logger.ch_id 
GROUP BY logger.lg_name, logger.lg_id, logger.created
ORDER BY logger.lg_tbl_id DESC
```

Comment: Let me try with this.